# C# MVC DropDown Onchange Remove the selected question for the next dropdown from the view bag

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build User identity questions view page .Once user selects  on question I want to remove the question from the list for next dropdown,as of now I am selecting the questions from a viewbag,Need to delete the selected question in the next dropdown box,Any on can help please.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="loginPanel col-centered" style="width:700px">
        <section id="loginForm">
            <form action="/" class="loginForm" id="form0" method="post" role="form" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="form-horizontal" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:800px">
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <hr />
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Question1, new SelectList(ViewBag.Questions, "value"), new { id = "Question1",, @class = "form-control", style = "width:500px; overflow:hidden" })

                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question1)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", }) })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Answer1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer1)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Question2, new SelectList(ViewBag.Questions, "value"), new { id = "Question2", @class = "form-control", style = "width:500px; overflow:hidden" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question2)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Answer2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer2)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Question3, new SelectList(ViewBag.Questions, "value"), new { id = "Question3", @class = "form-control", style = "width:500px; overflow:hidden" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Question3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Answer3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Answer3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Answer3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-sharp btn-orange" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
```

I know I need to write a javascript code for updating the view bag,can you please let me how to proceed as I am very new to this MVC.

Comment: What is inside `ViewBag.Questions` ?

Comment: List of the questions,The general Identity questions like Mother Medin name,Where were your born,Date of birth,Each one is a single string value.

Comment: You basically need to listen to the change event on the SELECT element's and update the other item content as needed.(excluding the currently selected value)

Comment: _I know I need to write a javascript code for updating the view bag_ - No you do not. `ViewBag` is server side code and javascript is client side code. You javascript code needs to update the DOM elements.